# $\zeta (1/2 + i) = 0$, correct?

Tags: riemann-zeta

Plugging $\zeta (1/2 + i)$ into Wolfram Alpha yields me some complex number, but I was under the understanding that $\zeta (1/2 + it) = 0$, for all $t$ we have yet calculated...

Is Wolfram Alpha just messing with me?

Thanks!

Comment: I believe your claim is incorrect.

Comment: All non-trivial zeros of the zeta function are *on the form* $z=1/2 + it$, it's not that every number on that form is a zero.

Comment: Oh! Man. That makes so much more sense. He he thanks!

Comment: $\zeta(1/2+i) \sim 0.1439364271 - 0.7220997435 i$

Comment: The Riemann hypothesis is that *if* $\zeta(z)=0$ (and $z$ is not a trivial zero) *then* $z=1/2+it$ for some real $t.$ This is not the same as saying that all values of $t$ give zeros of the zeta function.

Answer (score 1):

No! Every $s$ such that $\zeta(s)=0$ is assumed to be of the form $1/2 + i t$ yet not every $1/2 + i t$ is a root of $\zeta$.

Recall for example that $\zeta$ is a meromorphic function and as such can only have countably many roots.

Comment: Silly me! Thank you. I need to research that to find some solutions then!

Comment: There are many tables of roots. See http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RiemannZetaFunctionZeros.html for a few.

Comment: @Bliebervik: It is okay. Zeta function is not easy to study. To find a root by hand is quite difficult for people not working in the field.

Answer (score 1):

Wolfram alpha is correct. Note this for only some $t\in \mathbb{R}$ we have $\zeta(1/2+it)=0$ which are the non trivial zeroes.